# Click a button under a data-bind written by JavaScript using Python Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm able to login to a website but I couldn't figure it out how to click "Download as CSV".
I've tried XPATH and CSS Selector.

Here is the picture of the HTML.
[image]

The dashboard is combined with many widgets. Don't know if that would impact anything. 
[image]
Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you  : )

Below is code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

#### location of chrome 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'F:\User\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')

#### log in website 1
driver.get('https://www.yardipca.com/39444siteminderlive/')

### 1st door ( login& password)
name_1st = driver.find_element_by_name('USER')
name_1st.clear()
name_1st.send_keys('my_account')

passowrd_1st = driver.find_element_by_name('PASSWORD')
passowrd_1st.clear()
passowrd_1st.send_keys('my_password')

### login botton
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/div/center/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]/input[6]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,"P260 Live System (SAN/HOC)"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="acceptButton"]'))).click()

time.sleep(10)




#### log in website 2
driver.get('https://www.yardiasptx11.com/39444p260livehoc/jsp/index.jsp')

### 2nd door ( login& password)
name_2nd = driver.find_element_by_name('userId')
name_2nd.send_keys('my_account')

passowrd_2nd = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
passowrd_2nd.send_keys('my_password')

### login botton
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//[@id="standardLoginForm"]/div[3]/button'))).click()
time.sleep(5)

### Dropdown button
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="widget_937242"]/div[1]/div[1]'))).click()

# //*[@id="widget_937242"]/div[1]/div[1]
# //*[@id="widget_937242"]/div[1]/div[1]/a
# //*[@id="widget_937242"]/div[1]/div[1]/a/span

### download file
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#widget_937242 > div.panel-heading.ui-sortable-handle > div.btn-group.pull-right.print-hide.open > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a'))).click()



time.sleep(10)
```

The error popped up.

File "f:\User\Downloads\yardi.py", line 57, in

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="widget_937242"]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E96vX.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E96vX.png)'))).click()

File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the widget is always in the same place, I typically try clicking by using X/Y coordinates with a macro tool like AppRobotic if you're running this on Windows. If it's an issue with the page loading slowly, I usually try stopping the page load, and interacting with the page a bit, something like this should work for you:

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch
x = win32com.client.Dispatch("AppRobotic.API")
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
# wait 20 seconds
x.Wait(20000)
# scroll down a couple of times in case page javascript is waiting for user interaction
x.Type("{DOWN}")
x.Wait(2000)
x.Type("{DOWN}")
x.Wait(2000)
# forcefully stop pageload at this point
driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
# if clicking Download as CSV button with Selenium still does not work here, use screen coordinates
x.MoveCursor(xCoord, yCoord)
x.MouseLeftClick
x.Wait(2000)
```

Comment: thx for your reply. How do I find the coordinates of a certain tag?

Comment: I grab XY coords with the UI Item Explorer utility in AppRobotic, and typically macro programs have utilities that do this: https://superuser.com/questions/244267/program-for-getting-the-cursors-x-y-coordinates

Comment: after all the research and testing, I found there are several iframes within my website and thus once I switch the specific iframe, I'm able to click the drop-down list : )

Answer (score 0):

It's within the iframe so I switch the iframe that I want o act on.