# Python Selenium - Button click does not work in Chrome controlled window

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The submit button does not get clicked when tried in the window which is opened by Chrome driver (*Even tried hitting the button manually in the Chrome controlled window*) in the Automated run(*Using pytest selenium-python*).

**However there is no issue with the button in the application as I am able to click the same button manually in the application.**

Below is the HTML for the submit button:

```
 <a title="Submit" rel="tool" data-placement="bottom" data-bind="click: showSubmitPopup, css: {'btn': true, 'disabled': workflow.isDirty()}, visible: work.id() != null" class="btn" style="">
          <i class="ka ja-jw ka-play"></i>
        </a>
```

I tried the below methods which didn't work:

```
1.) driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[title='Submit'] > .a").click()
2.) driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', element)
3.) ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(element, 0, 0).perform()
4.) driver.get_action_driver().move_to_element(element).click().perform()
5.) Updated the chrome & chrome driver to latest version
```

Any pointers appreciated !!

Comment: What error are you getting here? BTW 2,3,5 are not performing click...

Comment: @Prophet I get an error ```Error Finding Element``` for the next element after the submit button .... so issue here is selenium is able to click on the above submit button but click is not successful although its been clicked, so the error is thrown for the subsequent next element as Selenium already clicked the current Submit button

Comment: I had tried 2,3 & 5 assuming element was not clickable but later realised that the element click is being done by selenium but its not successful.

Comment: html you shared for the button is the same across all browsers?

Comment: yes @itronic1990

Comment: its a bit strange as I am able to click the button normally but when the same is done Manually or by selenium in the Chrome controlled window the click fails.

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: sorry the app is accessible only using the corp vpn

Comment: I think I saw something like this sometimes. It wasn't the selenium code issue, not locator etc problem.

Comment: This issue is consistent for me, can't make out the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with Selenium as the click operation fails.

The workaround here is to refresh the webpage just before selenium attempts to click on the button.

Answer (score 1):

Can you give a try using the below way

```
# Find Element using Xpath
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='btn' and @title='Submit']")

# Click on the button using Javascript Executor
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: This does not work either, same issue in which element is clicked but not successful

Comment: Okay, I think you may want to look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57046606/click-a-button-under-a-data-bind-written-by-javascript-using-python-webdriver. The answer given mentions of capturing X-Y co-ord and performing mouse actions. I guess that is the only way here. If not, verify for frames present for this button ( This most likely is the case )

Comment: There are no IFrames in the app, Just for FYI `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[title='Submit'] > .a").click()` this used to work without issues. I doubt screen coordinate workaround will also work either as the click operation is happening but isn't successful, but will try.